# How to get generator of this Gaussian contraction semigroup?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, brownian-motion, heat-equation, semigroup-of-operators

$X=C_0(\mathbb R^n)$ is the closure of Schwartz function space $\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$ under the $L^{\infty}(\mathbb R^n)$ norm. Define
$$ 
  T_tu=\left\{
                \begin{aligned}
                        &\frac{1}{t^{\frac n2}}G\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt t}\right)*u,\,t>0,\\
                        &u, t=0,
                        \end{aligned}
                \right.
 $$
where $G$ is the Heat-kernel $p_l$ for $l=1$:
$$G(x)=\frac{1}{({4 \pi})^{\frac{n}{2}}}e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{4}}.$$
Then $T_t$ is a strong continous contraction semigroup.

> Show that the generator of $T_t$ is $A=\Delta$, $\mathcal D(A)=\{ u\in C_0:\Delta u\in C_0\}$.

I proved that $T_t$ is a strong continous contraction semigroup. But I cannot get its generator.

Answer (score 2):

I denote by $$p_t(x)=\frac{1}{(2\pi t)^{n/2}}e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{4t}}.$$
the Heat-kernel.
Since $u\in \mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$, your claim is equivalent to prove that $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\frac{\hat p_h \hat u-\hat u}{h}=\widehat{\frac{1}{2}\Delta u},$$
where $$\hat f(\xi):=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\int_{\mathbb R^d}e^{-i\xi\cdot x}f(x)\,\mathrm d x\quad \text{and}\quad \widehat{\Delta f}(\xi)=-\xi^2\hat f(\xi).$$

Therefore, the claim is equivalent to $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{h\psi}g-g}{h}=\psi g,\quad g\in \mathcal S(\mathbb R^n),$$
where $\psi(\xi)=-\frac{\xi^2}{2}$. To see the statement, consider
$$\Phi(z):=\frac{e^z-1}{z}=\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{z^{n-1}}{n!}.$$
Then, for $g\in \mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$,
$$\left\|\frac{e^{\psi h}g-g}{h}-\psi g\right\|_{L^2}^2=\|\Phi\circ (h\psi)\cdot \psi g\|_{L^2}^2=\int_{\mathbb R^n}\left|\Phi\left(-\frac{h\xi^2}{2}\right)\right|^2\left|\frac{\xi^2}{2}g(\xi)\right|^2\,\mathrm d \xi\underset{h\to 0}{\longrightarrow }0,$$
where the last equality comes from the *dominated convergence theorem*, and the claim follows.

Comment: We need to show that the convergence is under the L^{\infty} norm, but not L^2

Comment: No you need the convergence on $\mathcal D(A)$... so up to a sub-sequence, the claim follow...

Comment: but we need h tend to 0, not a subsequence?